# Why are IntelliSense suggestions not working in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have been using VSCode for programming in Python, but recently the IntelliSense suggestions have not been working properly.
Instead of suggesting variable or function names when I write them, IntelliSense suggests strange sorcerer words such as `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`.

How do I fix this?

[image: VSCode Intellinsence suggesting "from_trans_import_gettext", when it should suggest "tags"]

I have checked VSCode settings such as inline, restarted the IDE and refreshed my extensions, expecting IntelliSense to work again, without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that there are some errors in Pylance. Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot:

1. Use VSCode command **Developer: Reload Window**.
2. Select your Python Interpreter by shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose your python interpreter.
3. Add `"python.languageServer": "Pylance",` to your workspace `settings.json`.
4. If none of the above works, you can try to update VSCode and Python extension. You can also switch the python extension to **pre-release** version.